# Apply byte[] effect in c#

Tags: c#, image, arrays, effects, bitmapdata

I have a bitmap image and a byte[]. The byte[] contains an effect such as noise (in my case, byte[] contains custom effect). I want to apply this byte[] effect to the bitmap image and save the resulted bitmap.

I have the BitmapData and byte[] but I don't know how to mix merge these together?

Thanks

Update:

Well the byte[] contains the effect similar to cloths texture (net of threads, etc etc). I have the plane bitmap image of single color such as red, blue, violet... it may be of any color. I want to apply this cloth texture to this plane bitmap so that it can produce a bitmap image which looks like similar to cloth of the specific color.

I could also use any other method to get the above effect other than byte[] effect.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about your effect? It really depends on what the effect is. You could have an add operation, or a XOR, or a AND, etc etc...

Comment: To merge the 2 together, you will need to know how to do 2d procedural drawing.

Answer (score 0):

what about calculating the median for each pixel?

```
byte median = (int)(origignalpixel + noisepixel)/2;
```

you do this for every pixel component (red,green,blue).